# How to iterate through and compare a string with manual input in pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio, dataframe

I have the following pandas data table:
[image]

The above image is just the data I got from yfinance for AAPL stock
newsdf is the pandas data frame that has bunch of dates from another API call that has dates for specific news

I have the following code:

```
df['Boolean'] = df['Open'] < df['Close']
print(df)

if df['Boolean'] == 'False':
    for h in range(0, k):
        if newsdf[h] == df['Date']:
            print('Bearish signal ')
            print(h)
        else:
           print('Signal bullish')
```

I am getting the error: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Edit: I see that I am comparing the whole Boolean and I can't do that but what would be a way for me to iterate through the Boolean column, see if the value is ''True'' or ''False'', compare the value with the newsdf and print that index

Comment: What is `k` in your code?

Comment: `df['Boolean']` is an entire column of values, either `True` or `False`, with some of each.  You are trying to compare that entire column against a single string, `"False"`, which will never be true.  But you can't treat the whole column as a single value.

Comment: @Tuqay k is the len(list1) basically the row of the dataframe

Comment: @TimRoberts so I just need a for loop right before it?

Comment: @TimRoberts how would you iterate through just the boolean column to check if its false?

Comment: screen-shots do not help with debugging/reproducing it, can you pls paste the data of df vs screenshot? so what is the use case? so you have a list of dates and those are  in newdf as newdf[h], then you need to see for those dates => `df['Boolean']` is false and two dates does not match ?

Comment: you should rather use `df['Boolean'] == 'False'` to filter rows and use result with `for`-loop (instead of `range(0, k)`) - something like `for row in df[ df['Boolean'] == 'False' ]:` BTW: you may have similar problem with `... == df["Date"]` because you compare with all values in column `"Date"` and you should use `row["Date"]`

Comment: @simpleApp hey the data imported is quite large, its actually just from yfinance the data for aaple stock for the period 1 year

Comment: when i do df['Boolean'] == 'False' i think it makes all the values for it false i dont think its filtering it atleast thats what i see when i print it out

Answer (score 1):

try this, comments have been put against the line of code.

```
#package import
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

#data setup
newdf=pd.DataFrame({"h":['2021-01-04']})

raw_data= \
'''
Date Open Boolean
2021-01-04 132 False
2021-01-05 120 True
2021-01-06 123 False
'''
df=pd.read_csv(StringIO(raw_data),sep=" ")

#function to have a use case logic
def check_the_signal(df_row,newdf=newdf):
    
    if not df_row['Boolean']: # this is false
        if df_row['Date'] in list(newdf['h']): # caution when newdf is large dataset,list will be large 
            return 'Bearish signal '
        else:
            return 'Signal bullish'
    else:
        return "Neutral" # added for demo only!
df['single']=df.apply(check_the_signal,axis=1)# axis == 1 will send data at row level , saving the value in df, in case needed
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks for responding. I have a few questions so what does newdf do, like i see that its making a new column with data 2021-01-04, so for my case what would this be, I am having hard time understanding

Comment: i got that from your code snippet `if newsdf[h] == df['Date']` , so instead of a large data frame, i create a data frame with just one column using dictionary `{"h":['2021-01-04']}`.

Comment: so I just need this df=pd.read_csv(StringIO(yahoo.csv),sep=" ") and print(df) to see what it did and when i print it i dont get the table

Comment: if possible would you be able to comment each and every line lol also is it possible for you to get data from yfinance lol

Comment: i think the stringIo doesn't work with csv files?

Comment: i have used `stringIo` as i did not have your CSV. You just need `df=pd.read_csv(yahoo.csv,sep=" ")`

Comment: so when I do that and do the df['boolean'] = df['Open] < df['Close'] i get error, basically I was trying to create new column after comparing open and close prices from the original dataframe since it did not have the boolean column, when i dodf = pandas.read_csv(StringIO('yahoo.csv'), sep = " ") and try to make a new boolean column it gives me error